# Ansible, read from file and save it to another file

Tags: ansible

Let's say i have file-1.conf contains

```
conf1:"klop"
conf2:"rty"
```

I want to read conf1 and save it to other file. so that file-2.conf will contains

```
conf2:"rty"
... some other configurations
```

All the modules i have found manipulate files at the same instance. is there anyway to achieve this or to read this lines and save it to variables?

---

what is actually happening is that i install new deb package with new configurations (almost all configurations changed) so the old configuration is deleted. But i need to get some elements of the old configuration before i delete it and place it in the new one, like the example mentioned in the question.

I could write script that do this, but it will be better if ansible have a way to do this.

Comment: What is your expected output? `conf2:"klop"`?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i updated the question with what should file-2.conf will be

Comment: Your example output has no apparent bearing on the contents of the other file. It might make a little more sense if you post the actual file contents and the expected outcome of your play

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i hope new explanation make question clear, i cannot place the actual configuration file here as it is too large.

Comment: You say you need some elements from a default configuration file before you replace it.  But those default configuration files are typically just hardcoded or contain values that the package manager was able to evaluate.  Can you give us a more detailed explanation of what pieces of what configuration file you are trying to replicate?  There may be a better way of dealing with this than trying to copy arbitrary lines from one configuration file and pasting them into a new configuration file.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this?

Comment: @Chris_vr for one line of configuration  i used shell module with grep command and register the stdout to variable, then used this variable after creating the new file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using template functionality. Create a parametric template configuration file, and within your role, maintain a variable list you want to configure.
As you update your packages, the new template are applied, and the parameters that you want to maintain are read from variable file, which hasn't changed since previous version.